# the difference "I hate it if..." between "I hate it when..."

Tags: conditional-constructions

> 1)Mike would hate it **if** he lost Jane again. 2)Mike would hate it **when** he lost Jane again.

Supposing Jane came back to Mike again after two years of estrangement, Mike would never let Jane go.

Which sentence should I pick, 1) or 2)?

Comment: If I were Jane, I'd run far away.

Comment: "If"  - it might happen; "when" - it will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is written in the conditional mood (probably Second Conditional). In this case the condition is 'if [Mike] lost Jane again'.

The second sentence is written in the indicative mood. '[W}hen he lost Jane again', is not a condition it is factual statement regarding something that happened in the past ('lost' is past tense). As this is not a conditional sentence we cannot say 'Mike would hate' because this is a conditional construction using the auxiliary 'would'. This sentence could be written as:

> Mike will hate it when he loses Jane again.

So, if you want to say that it is possible that Jane will leave Mike again, and that Mike will hate this if it happens, your first sentence is the one you should pick.

Comment: But all the things were happened in the past, like a line from a novel describing events that took place before.

Comment: The phrase 'Mike would hate it if...' implies a future hypothetical event, not something that has occurred in the past. If you are talking about an event that actually occurred in the past you can say 'Make hated it when Jane left him again' or possibly 'Mike would have hated it when Jane left him again'. If you are talking about a hypothetical event that could have happened in the past you can say 'Mike would have hated it if Jane had left him again'.